# DifferentialEquations hands in "nothing" to my differential equation

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I'm attempting to solve the two body differential equation. DifferentialEquations.jl used to solve my equation with no trouble, but at some point, it started handing in `nothing` for the initial condition to differential equation.

Is this potentially a problem with the scoping stuff that's been coming up a lot recently?

```
using Unitful, RecursiveArrayTools, DifferentialEquations

function propagateTrajNewWay(df::DataFrame, idx::Int)
    x  = df.E[idx]u"m"
    y  = df.F[idx]u"m"
    z  = df.G[idx]u"m"
    r0 = [x, y, z]
    vx = df.dE[idx]u"m/s"
    vy = df.dF[idx]u"m/s"
    vz = df.dG[idx]u"m/s"
    v0 = [vx, vy, vz]
    rv0 = ArrayPartition(r0, v0)
    tspan = (df.time[idx]u"s", df.time[end]u"s")
    μ = 3.986004418e14u"m^3/s^2"
    # prob = ODEProblem(twoBody, u0, tspan)
    # println(prob)
    # sol = solve(prob, VCABM(), reltol = 1e-12, abstol = 1e-12)
    prob = ODEProblem((t, y, dy) -> twoBodyNew(t, y, dy, μ), rv0, tspan)
    sol = solve(prob, VCABM())
    return sol
end

function twoBodyNew(t, y, dy, μ)
    show(y)
    r = norm(y.x[1])
    dy.x[1] .= y.x[2]
    dy.x[2] .= -μ .* y.x[1] / r^3
end


function propWholeTraj(df)
    for ii = 1:size(df, 1)
        propagateTrajNewWay(df, ii)
    end
end

propWholeTraj(df)
```

The code that's in here is basically copied verbatim from [this page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/diffeq_arrays.html) on
using static arrays. I also have my own version of the two body function and the function that sets up and calls it, but this also has the same error.

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature should be `twoBodyNew(t, y, μ, dy)`. It's always `((du),u,p,t)`. The docs on that linked page have been fixed.

Comment: Just to clarify, all of the docs on that page are correct? I tried again with those equations exactly, but it still isn't working for me

Comment: Did you follow the docs after they were updated? I updated them after your post to fix the error.

Comment: Yea, I copied and pasted the code there into a separate script and ran that, but still got the same "nothing" error

Comment: Actually, I should add that the Unitful use hasn't been working for me here. I'm getting `ERROR: LoadError: DimensionError: km s^-1 and 0.0 are not dimensionally compatible.` So I have been cutting the units out of the code

Comment: I also had to add `using LinearAlgebra` otherwise `norm` was undefined. I'm now getting just `ERROR: LoadError: type Float64 has no field x` corresponding to the line `dy.x[1] .= y.x[2]`

Comment: The issue seems to be a regression in Unitful.jl on v1.0: https://github.com/ajkeller34/Unitful.jl/issues/159 . Hopefully we can get that fixed. StackOverflow likely isn't the right forum for bug tracking though, so would you mind opening an issue?

Comment: I opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/348

Comment: IMPORTANT UPDATE: Having copied and pasted the code on the linked page (http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/features/diffeq_arrays.html) as of right now, everything now works!

Comment: The unitful problem has a fix. Once Unitful.jl merges and tags https://github.com/ajkeller34/Unitful.jl/pull/163 or equivalent it'll be good to go on v1.0.